# MySQL updating a field with comma if a value already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, case

How can I execute an update query on a field in a table by checking in the query itself that if the field is empty or not. If it's empty then perform a normal update else update by adding a comma with the new value.

For example:

Say in table `users` I have a field named `genders`.

**Case 1:** The field is empty for the chosen row. Update value `male`.

**Case 2:** The field is not empty and has a value (for example, `male`). Update with `,female`. Now the field value becomes `male,female`.

**Case 3:** If field is not empty and has a value then keep a check to not repeat the update. For example, field has `male,female` and update query is run again then the it will update `male,female,female` as per `CASE 2`. This should be avoided.

I want to perform this within the query itself. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: No, no, no, no! Don't store multiple values in a single column

Comment: If you really need then check https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_case.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_concat.asp at least for learning purpose.

Comment: @juergend it will only store 2 values at max. Not an issue. No normalization needed here. I understand the importance of normalization but that's only for larger values or records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an idea from following and modify the query according to your requirement.

```
UPDATE users SET genders = CASE
    WHEN genders = '' OR genders is null THEN 'male'
    WHEN genders ='male' THEN CONCAT(genders,',','female') 
    WHEN genders ='female' THEN CONCAT(genders,',','male') 
    ELSE genders
    END
```

Comment: I was just doing this already when you posted. But thanks :)

Comment: Please update your query to check for `IS NULL` as well like this `WHEN (genders = '' OR genders IS NULL)`. This will cover up any loop hole for null or empty checks.

Comment: Bro I have an issue. This is updating `male,female,female,female`. Case 2 is being repeated when the query is run again. I have updated the question with Case 3.

Comment: hope the answer helps

Comment: I had given genders just for a dummy example. I was using logged in user ID here. In my case I had to use `FIND_IN_SET` for `NOT NULL` condition.